# Should we ask and answer questions we already know the answer to?

Tags: discussion

Say we had a question and couldn't manage to find a solution on Stack Overflow, but then figured out the solution by other means. Would it be viable to ask the question anyway, and then answer it ourselves simply so that others could see the solution?

Comment: yes that would be a great idea providing there is not already a solution and you make the question and answer as detailed as possible for anyone to follow

Comment: Try to formulate the question as if you _didn't_ know the answer, with as much information as possible so someone else could also, theoretically, answer it. Self-answering is fine, but it is not easy, and the posts need to stand in their own feet anyway.

Comment: There is no "should".  You *can* post a self-answered question.  Make sure you needed at least a couple of hours to find the solution.

Comment: Self-answered questions are held to a higher standard. Theoretically, this is because you need to show >1 person is interested (as opposed to a normal question, where both the questioner & answerer are interested). Truthfully, the SO regulars as a whole are a suspicious bunch. They think that self-answered Q&A is either for rep-hunting or canonicals (which are also for rep-hunting). You need not hold yourselves to their standard (I don't); just be prepared for downvotes if your Q&A isn't perfect.

Comment: Don't listen to Hans requirement.. Just ask the question as if you don't know the answer, and answer it as if you did not ask it. SO is a place for *every* programming question, not just ones that take a couple of hours to find the solution.